# Word or phrase that refers to the person who is the "focus" in a video?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the case of, for example,  birthday and wedding recordings, what do you call the people who are the main focus of the video (e.g. bride, groom and birthday boy/girl)?

Example:

> All the [……] of the videos shared something in common.

Comment: Subject comes to mind

Comment: Hello, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing yours to *“What do you call the people....?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about everybody in the video you could say "the entire ***cast*** of the video".

For a single person you can use ***[protagonist](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protagonist)***

> the leading character or one of the major characters in a play, film, novel, etc.:

..or you can indeed have multiple protagonists.

If that is too cinematic for your needs, you could use ***subjects*** as suggested by @mplungjan or something like:

> All of the *people featured* in the videos...

Or, if you want to highlight the key people you can use ***stars*** as answered by Mark.  This would suggest the main "characters" and not those in the background.

Comment: Well, it's just a recording. Not a film nor anything like that.

Comment: @janoChen See edits.

Answer (score 2):

Simply "**star**" or "leading man / lady / person" ?

Comment: Like: "The people who starred in those videos?"

Answer (score 2):

In TV broadcasts, they use "anchors". But that's presenters, mostly.
Main characters are "protagonists".